# WebViewWidget inside a GestureDetector, not registering taps

Tags: flutter, webview, gesturedetector

In the following code only the WebViewWidget register taps and the onTap is never called.

what am I doing wrong?

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
    body: GestureDetector(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
      onTap: () => resetInactivityTimer(),
      child: WebViewWidget(
        controller: _webViewController,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Thank you in advance

I tried combinations of both but never achieved the goal.

Answer (score 2):

In the end I found this solution that works by wrapping the WebViewWidget inside Listener instead of a GestureDetector and listening for OnPointerDown:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            Listener(
                behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                onPointerDown: (_) => resetInactivityTimer(),
                child: WebViewWidget(
                  controller: _webViewController,
                ))
          ],
        ));
  }
```

This solution worked the best for me

Answer (score 0):

Try using this package: https://pub.dev/packages/pointer_interceptor , apparently that solves it (as noted per https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/58659)